# Descriptor class design in Python (with inheritance)

Tags: python, class, inheritance, descriptor

I'm trying to design a descriptor class which I can use through other class which is a subclass of a class which is a subclass of a class.

```
class MyDescriptorClass(object):
    def __init__(self, owner, name, activates = 0):
        self.value = None
        self.name = name
        self.owner = owner
        self.activates = 0
        self.connects = []

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        self.set(val)
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value

    def set(self, value):
        if self.value  == value:
            return 0
        self.value = value
        if self.activates:
            self.owner.evaluate()

    def connect(self, inputs):
        if not isinstance(inputs, list): 
            inputs = list(inputs)
        for input in inputs: 
            self.connects.append(input)

class ParentClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.states = {}
        self.name = name
        self.A = MyDescriptorClass(self, name, activates = 1)    
        self.B = MyDescriptorClass(self, name, activates = 1)
        self.states.setDefault('A', self.A)
        self.states.setDefault('B', self.B)

class ChildClass1(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, name)
        super(ChildClass1, self).__init__(name)
        self.ans = None
    def evaluate(self):
        self.ans = self.A.value + self.B.value

class ChildClass2(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self, name)
        super(ChildClass1, self).__init__(name)
        self.ans = None
    def evaluate(self):
        self.ans = self.A.value * self.B.value
```

`self.A = MyDescriptorClass()` will not work according to the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)

so the only way is that I declate `A = MyDescriptorClass()` in the `ParentClass` as

```
class ParentClass(object):
    A = MyDescriptorClass() # here I am unable to pass the owner
```

And since, I'm using a child class, `super` call skips this part and starts directly with `__init__`

Is there any way in which I can modify the design so as to set the value of `ChildClass1.A` instance directly?

```
  c = ChildClass1("c1")
  c.A = 10 # I directly want to set this value instead of using c.A.set(10)
  c.B = 20
  c.evaluate()
  print c.ans # 30
  c.B = 40
  print c.ans # 50
```

Comment: So you need the owner to be the `ParentClass` instead of the class being bound to?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question; no you cannot set descriptors as instance attributes, they must reside on the class. But I am not clear what you are trying to achieve with your descriptor.

Comment: Subclasses will inherit descriptors from their parent class hierarchy, so `self.A` will be available on `ChildClass2` if `A` is a class attribute.

Comment: Your descriptor sets values directly on the descriptor instance; you probably want to set those on the owner instance instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try not to put information which is specific to *instances* in the descriptor. Keep information specific to instances in instance attributes, and keep information specific to the descriptor (like `activates`) in the descriptor:

```
class MyDescriptorClass(object):
    def __init__(self, activates = 0):
        self.value = None
        self.activates = activates
        self.connects = []

    def __set__(self, instance, val):      # 1
        if self.value == val:
            return 0
        self.value = val
        if self.activates:
            instance.evaluate()
    def __get__(self, instance, instcls):  # 1 
        return self.value
```

1. Note that the `__set__` and `__get__` methods are passed the
   `instance` which is accessing the descriptor. Therefore, you do not
   need to store the `owner` in MyDescriptor. The `instance` is the
   `owner`.

---

Given the clarification of the problem in the comments below, here is how I would implement the descriptor.

```
class GateInput(object):
    def __init__(self, index):
        self.index = index                    # 4

    def __get__(self, inst, instcls):
        return inst.inputs[self.index].ans    # 5

    def __set__(self, inst, val):
        if isinstance(val, (float, int)):
            inst.inputs[self.index] = Constant(val)
        else:
            inst.inputs[self.index] = val


class Constant(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.ans = val


class Gate(object):
    A = GateInput(0)               # 1  
    B = GateInput(1)               # 1

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.inputs = [Constant(0), Constant(0)]    # 2


class Adder(Gate):
    @property
    def ans(self):
        result = 0
        for gate in self.inputs:
            result += gate.ans                      # 3
        return result


class Multiplier(Gate):
    @property
    def ans(self):
        result = 1
        for gate in self.inputs:
            result *= gate.ans
        return result

b = Multiplier('b1')
b.A = 2
b.B = 3
print(b.A)
# 2
print(b.ans)
# 6

c = Adder('c1')
c.A = 10
print(c.ans)
# 10

# This connects output of b to an input of c
c.B = b
print(c.ans)
# 16
```

1. Descriptors have to be defined as class attributes, not instance
   attributes. Since the descriptor is accessed by *all* instances, you
   probably do not want the descriptor to change merely because an
   instance is being created. Therefore, do not instantiate the
   descriptor in `__init__`.
2. Each instance of Gate has a list of inputs. The items self.inputs
   are instances of Constant or Gate.
3. Here we see the purpose of the Constant class. For every `gate`,
   `gate.ans` needs to return a value.
4. The index records which item in inst.inputs the `GateInput` is
   connected to.
5. inst is an instance of Gate. For example, `c.A` causes Python to
   call `GateInput.__get__(self, c, type(c))`. Thus, `inst` is `c`
   here.

Comment: This works fine. However, I can't use `connect`.


c = ChildClass1('c1');

b = ChildClass2('b1');

c.A.connect(b.A);


This gives `AttributeError` that `NoneType` object has no attribute `connect`

Comment: Do you want the `connects` list to be associated with the instance `c` (i.e. should there be a different `connects` list for each instance), or do you want all instances of `ParentClass` to potentially alter the same `connects` list?

Comment: What does the `connects` list have to do with `MyDescriptClass`? What is it doing there? Wouldn't it make more sense to put the `connect` method in `ParentClass`?

Comment: I'm making something like logic circuits. So `ParentClass` here is `Gate` with 2 input value and 1 output value. `And Gate` would be a children of this class. and `DescriptorClass` is for connections. so if the output of Gate 1 goes to input A of Gate 2.

Answer (score 0):

As it is int he comments: 
descriptors must be class attributes, not instance attributes in order to work - 
so, to start with:

```
class ParentClass(object):
    A = MyDescriptorClass()
    B = MyDescriptorClass()
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.states = {}
        self.name = name
        self.A.configure(self, name, activates = 1)    
        self.B.configure(self, name, activates = 1)
        self.states.setDefault('A', self.A)
        self.states.setDefault('B', self.B)
```

And then you fix your Descriptor class accordingly:
either have then keeping all data refering to an instance in the instance itself
(that is why `__get__` and `__set__` receive the object itself) - or have
each descriptor instance have a dictionary where they can annotate data related
to the instances of the class they belong too, by, for example, object ID.

Your descriptor class could be more or less along these lines:

```
class MyDescriptorClass(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.data = defaultDict(dict)
    def configure(self, owner, name, activates = 0):
        container = self.data(id(owner))
        container["value"] = None
        container["name"] = name
        ...

    def __set__(self, owner, value):
        # implemnt your previous "set" method straight here
        ...  
        ...
```

Comment: I was trying this. but it shows `self.A` as `NoneType` object and throws `AttributeError`